# How can I check for a specific object (by multiple properties) in API response using Playwright javascript

Tags: javascript, playwright

I have an API that returns user types

```
const getAllUserTypes = await request.get(<requestURL>)
```

Response JSON:

```
{
  "UserTypes": [
    {
      "UserTypeId": 1,
      "UserType": "Admin"
    },
    {
      "UserTypeId": 2,
      "UserType": "Customer"
    },
    {
      "UserTypeId": 3,
      "UserType": "Support Agent"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to check whether the following object is present in that response

```
expectedObject = {
    "UserTypeId": 3,
    "UserType": "Support Agent"
}
```

I have tried `toMatchObject()` and `toEqual()` but these won't work

```
expect(await getAllUserTypes.json()).toMatchObject(expectedObject);
```

Note that, it should match all the properties exactly.

Comment: Why not test rendered output rather than API responses?

Comment: Note that the dupliate is speifically for finding by a single 'id' property, but this can easily be expanded to look for id and type, as required in your example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes

Comment: @evolutionxbox Can you please elaborate. I'm new to js. FYI, I wanted to test APIs using Playwright js.

Comment: Consider testing the endpoints directly? https://playwright.dev/docs/api-testing

Comment: @evolutionxbox I wanted to automate few endpoints